# Does the WCF HTTP binding run on TCP?

Tags: wcf, http, tcp, wcf-binding

I'm trying to understand the difference between the standard bindings in WCF. As part of this, I'm reading [WCF Bindings in Depth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163394.aspx). Figure 2 shows that there are bindings whose transport is HTTP and some which are TCP. I'm confused b/c I thought HTTP was an application-level protocol, not a transport protocol -- and that HTTP ran on top of TCP. So by calling it an HTTP binding, are we to understand that it's actually running on HTTP on top of TCP?

Comment: For others who may have the same question, Google the following: Octet, Ethernet Frame, IP Packet, TCP Segment, HTTP. See also http://www.vlsm-calc.net/models.php. My question stems from not really understanding these basic concepts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So by calling it an HTTP binding, are we to understand that it's
>   actually running on HTTP on top of TCP?

Yes, exactly. But that's implicit. Because HTTP runs on top of TCP.

The binary bindings (such as `netTcpBinding`) run directly on TCP. They do not use HTTP at all.

Answer (score 0):

tcp/ip contains 4 layers:

```
application
transport
network
data link
```

you can use any layer, but wcf has binding which use transport and application layers, f.e. `netTcpBinding` and `wsHttpBinding`

tpc/ip does not same tcp layer

```
application layer protocols f.e.: HTTP, RTP, FTP, DNS
transport layer protocols f.e.: TCP, UDP, SCTP, DCCP
```

so http can be based at UDP protocol and it will be `wsHttpBinding`
or if you choise tcp it will be `netTcpBinding`, this layer in below than http, and application is redundant